# CS50 results going berserk, and I have no idea why

Tags: c, cs50

I've seen a few Harvard CS50 questions on here, but none of them seem quite like what I'm dealing with.

I am a complete newbie with C, and because of that, I am probably missing something obvious here, so I beg your indulgence.

This is the "Readability" problem in which text is input, and the result of the program is to print out what grade the text is readable at, using the Coleman-Liau index, which is:

`index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8`

where L is the average number of letters per 100 words in the text, and S is the average number of sentences per 100 words in the text.

My code is currently:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

float perOneHundred (int wordTotal);
int grade(float forumulaAnswer);
float Coleman (int charTotal, int wordTotal, int sentenceTotal);

int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("Text:\n");
    int charTotal = 0;
    int wordTotal = 1;
    int sentenceTotal = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < (strlen(text)); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]) > 0)
        {
            charTotal++;
        }
        else if (text[i] == ' ')
        {
            wordTotal++;
        }
        else if (text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '?' || text[i] == '!')
        {
            sentenceTotal++;
        }
    }


    printf("Letters: %i\n Words: %i\n Sentences: %i\n", charTotal, wordTotal, sentenceTotal); //this is a test line.
    

    float answer = Coleman(charTotal, wordTotal, sentenceTotal);
    int level = grade(answer);

    return level;



}

float magic (int wordTotal)
{
    float magic = (100/wordTotal);
    return magic;
}

int grade(float formulaAnswer)
{
    if (formulaAnswer < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else if (formulaAnswer >= 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade %f.\n", round(formulaAnswer));
    }
    return 0;
}

float Coleman (int charTotal, int wordTotal, int sentenceTotal)
{
    float index = 0.0588 * (charTotal * ((magic(wordTotal)))) - 0.296 * ((magic(wordTotal)) * sentenceTotal) - 15.8;
    return index;
}
```

When the text input into the program is "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." my results are:

```
Before Grade 1
Before Grade 1
Grade 2.000000Before Grade 1
Before Grade 1
Before Grade 1
Grade 2.000000Grade 5.000000Grade 8.000000Before Grade 1
Grade 2.000000Grade 4.000000Grade 6.000000Grade 7.000000Grade 9.000000Grade 3.000000Grade 5.000000Grade 6.000000Grade 8.000000Grade 3.000000Grade 4.000000Grade 5.000000Grade 7.000000Grade 8.000000Grade 9.000000Grade 4.000000Grade 5.000000Grade 6.000000Grade 7.000000Grade 8.000000Grade 5.000000Grade 6.000000Grade 6.000000Grade 7.000000Grade 4.000000Grade 5.000000Grade 5.000000Grade 6.000000Grade 7.000000Grade 5.000000Grade 6.000000Grade 6.000000Grade 7.000000Grade 4.000000
```

Obviously I am looking for the solution here, but here is some of my thought process if it helps you to redirect my misconceptions and such.

1. The printing of multiple grades really only makes sense to me if the command to print was in a loop, since I only call the function that prints those lines once. Those lines are not in my loop. Why on earth is this happening?
2. Why does my test line not appear anywhere? The code below it is used. The code above it is used. Why is this skipped?
3. Since the loop should be incrementing up my three total variables, why is the grade bouncing back and forth? Shouldn't it just be the same grade over and over since the math should, using those variables, give the same answer over and over?

I apologize if this is very basic or very obvious, but I just don't see it.

All the best, and thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Thank you all for taking a look at the issue. For those mentioning I forgot <stdio.h>, I forgot to include it in the copy and paste. It was there in the code.

I am encouraged by people being unable to replicate the issue. Hopefully it means I'm more or less doing it correctly. However, just to show you what is happening I made a screencast of the error, found below.

https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cYj3b6mDmt

If you guys are stumped, then I think I should probably just turn it in, since I literally see absolutely no reason why this is still occurring.

All the best,

Sipe

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: `float magic = (100/wordTotal);` should be `float magic = (100.0/wordTotal);` Otherwise you do integer division.

Comment: Also unrelated: `if (isalpha(text[i]) > 0)` is bogus.  When a function returns non-zero to indicate a boolean truth, use it without comparing to anything: `if (isalpha(text[i]))`.

Comment: Let's go step by step with the debugging from errors, I have found:

 1. First off, you forgot `#include <stdio.h>` since you are using `printf()` function.
2. The next I would do is is change this line:


`printf("Grade %f.\n", round(formulaAnswer));`

to this instead so you don't get trailing zeros

    `printf("Grade %.0f.\n", round(formulaAnswer));`

I have been attempting to recreate your problem but I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: Are you sure that you're recompiling properly? And running the new binary, not some old one?